# How does the Pandas Histogram Data Get to the Graph without Passing it In?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib

Pretty straight forward question here.

I'm loading data in from a csv. The csv column for age is then converted into a histogram. Finally I'm showing a graph and the data is populated to it.

For the life of me though, I don't understand how the matplotlib `plt` is getting the data from the pandas command `dftrain.age.hist()` without me explicitly passing it in.

Is `hist` an extension method? That's the only thing that makes sense to me currently.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#load csv files 

##training data
dftrain = pd.read_csv('https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-datasets/titanic/train.csv')

#generate a histogram of ages
dftrain.age.hist()

#show the graph
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So according to this article I think internally the pandas hist function is calling the matploitlib hist function

https://www.educba.com/pandas-hist/

> Pandas hist() function is utilized to develop Histograms in Python
> using the panda’s library. A histogram is a portrayal of the
> conveyance of information. This capacity calls
> matplotlib.pyplot.hist(), on every arrangement in the DataFrame,
> bringing about one histogram for each section or column.

Answer (score 0):

every pandas dataframe in python is itself a class. So you can access its variables as usual with other python classes.

So when you code *dftrain.age*, you are accessing that column. And by *dftrain.age.hist()* you can just generate a histogram of the values of that column.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
  
# Creating the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'Weight':[45, 88, 56, 15, 71],
                   'Name':['Sam', 'Andrea', 'Alex', 'Robin', 'Kia'],
                   'Age':[14, 25, 55, 8, 21]})

print("Type of a dataframe: ",type(df))
print("Type of a dataframe column: ",type(df.Age))
print("Printing that column\n",df.Age)
```

Output will be this:

```
Type of a dataframe:  <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Type of a dataframe column:  <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
Printing that column
 0    14
 1    25
 2    55
 3     8
 4    21
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as to how mathplotlib is getting the pandas generated histogram data in order to display it when plt.show is called